# What's the time dilation ratio between Earth time and Wonderland time?

Tags: alice-in-wonderland

I recently watched the [Alice miniseries that aired on SciFi Network / Syfy back in 2009](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_%28TV_miniseries%29). I know that...

> Her time spent in Wonderland amounted only to an hour in Earth time.

However, how long was her stay in Wonderland-time? Over the course of the miniseries/film, we see one night, and The Queen mentions that Jack has been there for three days. At best, I can puzzle out that maybe a week has passed.

My real question, then: **What's the time dilation ratio between Earth time and Wonderland time?**

Comment: +1, great question! Now if only we had some sort of hats to reward awesome questions ... *SCNR* :)

Comment: @bitmask Touche, sir! :P

Comment: Is this specific to the mini series, the book or entire franchise?

Comment: @DVK specific to the miniseries.

Comment: @DVK I thought your edit was superfluous. I felt that I had made it clear in my opening paragraph that the time span I was looking at was directly from the miniseries. As such, I rolled it back.

Comment: @Aarthi - your call, but the fact that I was needed to ask means it wasn't 100% superfluous. My general asking and editing policy is that any helpful info OP provides in comments belongs to the main post, unless doing so would severely screw with an established answer.

Comment: @Aarthi: You say you made it clear in your first sentence, but you're tag is for `Alice in Wonderland`. The mini-series is simply called `Alice`. If I'm searching by tag, I would expect this to be about the book, and not the mini-series. DVK's edit was actually a fantastic edit to keep those like me from making assumptions based on the title and tag.

Answer (score 4):

### The time differential between the real world and Wonderland is wildly inconsistent.

The whole of the first episode, representing some 4-8 weeks of Wonderland time seems to have only taken around one hour in the real world. We can therefore approximate a time differential of around 1000:1

By comparison, Jack spends 6 weeks in the real world (which should equate to over a hundred years of subjective time in Wonderland) whereas only a few months seems to have passed, suggesting a ratio closer to 1:20 or less.

Later, Alice returns to our world mere *hours* after she left, but when the Hatter shows up the following morning (subjectively less than a couple of weeks later) he says "Finally!" implying that he's been waiting much, much longer. On the flip side, Alice's father seems to have aged no more than he would have in our world despite facing a time differential of over a thousand years.

TV tropes refers to this kind of inconsistency as "[Narnia Time](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NarniaTime)"